# Count of 3 digit numbers having digits in non-increasing order

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

What is the count of 3-digit positive numbers such that all the digits(from left to right) are in non-increasing order of value?

For e.g:

1. 633 is counted, as its digits from left to right are in non-increasing order, i.e. 6 >= 3 >= 3.
2. 323 is not counted, as its digits are not in non-increasing order.
   I have tried this question by creating cases for the middle digits starting from 0 to 9 but couldn't get the correct answer.
   The correct answer for this question is 219.
   It would be really helpful if someone can let me know how to solve this.

Comment: The less elegant approach, given the answer of SlipEternal, is to work backwards.  If the (10)'s digit is $k$, then there are $k$ possibilties for the one's digit.  If the (100)'s digit is $k$, then there are $k$ possibilities for the 10's digit.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a$ be the first digit, $b$ be the second digit, and $c$ be the third. So, our three digit number is $abc$. Now, let $x=a+2,y=b+1,z=c$. We now have a strictly decreasing set of three numbers taken from the set of numbers $0$ through $11$. Since they are strictly decreasing, any choice of three distinct representatives of the set of numbers from $0$ to $11$ yield a valid choice in decreasing order, which is in one-to-one bijection with a three digit nonincreasing number with one exception. $000$ is not a three digit number.

So, since the set of numbers from $0$ to $11$ has $12$ elements, the answer is:

$$\dbinom{12}{3}-1=219$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not able to understand 0 to 11. please help

Comment: Take any three digit number with $c$ being $0$. That gives us the lower bound. Take any three digit number with $a=9$. Then $a+2=11$ giving us the upper bound.

Comment: Thank You very for the clear explanation

Comment: One more doubt if we do 9+2 for x , won't it become a 4 digit number ?

Comment: $x,y,z$ are just three numbers. They are not digits. To get back to $abc$, which are digits, you need to use the inverse of the bijection: $a=x-2, b=y-1, c=z$. So, let's say you choose $x=11,y=10,z=9$. You get the number $999$ since $11-2=9, 10-1=9, 9=9$.

Comment: SlipEternal , Thank You. Where can i find this property of bijection, please help with any resource.

Comment: A bijection is a one-to-one mapping. You can read more about it in Wikipedia. Just type "bijection" into Google, and it will probably be the very first result.

Comment: SlipEternal , Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom{10+3-1}{3}=220$ [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) of $3$ digits taken from the set $\{0,1,\dots , 9\}$.  Each multiset can be arranged in non-increasing order in exactly one way.  But $000$ is not a three-digit number, so the number of three-digit numbers is $220-1=219$.

Comment: I think this should be the answer marked as "the answer".

Answer (score 1):

*Another way*

$3\;\;of\; a\; kind\;\;eg\;\; 666:\;\; \binom{10}1 = 10$

$2-1\;\; of\; a\; kind\;\;eg\;\;332:\;\;\binom{10}1\binom{9}1 = 90$

$1-1-1\;\; of\; a\;\; kind\;\;eg\;\;753:\;\; \binom{10}{3} = 120$

Now any three digit sequence can be non-increasing in only one way, so adding up and subtracting $1$ for $000$, we get the answer of $219$

Answer (score 0):

I wrote down the first cases to see if I could find a pattern. Indeed,

100, 110, 111
thats **3** digits between 100 and 199

200, 210, 211 as above, plus 220, 221, 222
thats **6** digits between 200 and 299 (with 3 of them being of the same form as above, and 3 of the form 22x)

300,310,311,320,321,322 as above plus 330,331,332,333
thats **10** digits between 300 and 399 (with 6 of them being of the same form as above, and 4 of the form 33x)

...

thats **55** digits between 900 and 999.

**The pattern is**:
Increasing to the next digit in the hundreds place allows for [next triangular number] more numbers that arise when the digit in the tens place is highest, = matches the digit upfront.

In other words: Starting with 3 that account for the onehundreds, you add 3 to get *6* for the twohundreds, than add 4 (to those 6) to get *10* for the threehundreds, than add 5 (to those 10) to get *15* for the fourhundreds, and so on. The numbers in italic are triangular numbers.

Thus, you have $3+6+10+15+21+28+36+45+55=219$

digits with your non-increasing property

Comment: I am not able to understand how you counted for the rest of the cases from 400 to 499 etc,..... How to get the series. Please help

Comment: From 400 to 499, same as between 300 and 399 plus another 5, so 15 in total. Every new number upfront in the hundreds place adds  the next triangular number.

Comment: Edited to explain the pattern, but please accept the much neater answer by @SlipEternal.